# In ontology development, where do axioms come from?

Tags: logic, formal-methods, first-order-logic, ontologies

I am developing an ontology. I've got the classes, relationships and I guess I could come up with instances at this point too.

But what I'm really focused on is the axioms. I've learnt that the axioms restrict the knowledge so that reasoning can be done which then reveals the consistency or satisfiability of the ontology as well as subsumption and some other things.

I want to know: where do the axioms come from?
Is there a formal method to coming with the axioms? Do I just dream them up and kind of decide, based on my knowledge of the domain, that these things are true and ought to be represented as such? If I had to substantiate my axioms and say where I came up with them, what would I say??